# Как добавить произвольную форму с заливкой в before?

Tags: html, css

Нужен 10х10 квардрат с заливкой цвета. Вроде всё верно делаю, но он не отображается.

```
.top ul li:before {
    content: "";
    background: #1b1b40;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: верстку добавьте в вопрос

Comment: Я же добавил кусок кода.

Comment: А мы можем знать как вы строете DOM модель? Всегда пишите все, на что указывает что-то в вашем коде. Быстрее и легче будет разобраться

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо добавить `display: block;` или `display: inline-block;`

```css
.top ul li:before {
    content: "";
    background: #1b1b40;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот что упустил, спасибо!

Comment: @Александр ответ можно принять нажатием галочки слева вверху